# Powershell Refolder by Filename Before Delim

Tags: performance, multithreading, file-system, formatting, powershell

I'm pretty new to Powershell but have been using it more and more to automate tasks at work. Now I'm reaching out for some help. I typically use the scripts I write in a way where I copy and paste the ps1 into the directory I want to perform the task on. Then double-clicking. That is why you'll see that the ps1 filename is used to create a variable. It allows me to create a sort of preset of ps1 depending on what I use them for. Ex: 00-Refolder.tif.ps1

In the example, files are grouped into a single folder based on the filename before an underscore. They are then moved using multithreading. I'm using Powershell 7.1.3. If anyone knows a way to dynamically set threads based on the PC for the `-Throttlelimit` parameter that would be great to know.

[Github version](https://github.com/shanestained/Refolder-Rename-PowerShell/blob/main/00-Refolder.tif.ps1) of this script.

Is there a more optimized way of performing this re-folder task? Whether it's a different way or just a more optimized version of the code below. If my formatting is off please let me know, that includes if you think a comment isn't worded correctly or could be more clear. I appreciate any help.

```
# Set the delim - all characters in the filenames before the delim will become the new folders.
$refolderDelim = '_'

# Set Threads for multithreading
$threads = 6

# Get the filename of the script to then use substrings of the filename to set variables. 
$scriptPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$scriptName = Split-Path $scriptPath -leaf

# The file type before .ps1 is used as the filter, The two .'s are used to replace, Text before the two .'s in the filename can be changed.
$fileType = $scriptName -replace ('^.+?\.','.') -replace ('.ps1')

Measure-Command {

# Filters files in the script's directory by filetype in script filename.
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *$fileType |
    Group-Object { $_.Name -replace ($refolderDelim + '.*') } |
        ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        
# Checks if folder exists and creates it if not
            if ( -Not ( Test-Path -Path $_.Name ) ) {
                $dir = New-Item -Type Directory -Name $_.Name
            }
            
# If folder does exist it only sets the $dir variable
            else {
                $dir = $_.Name
            }
# Filenames are moved to the repective folder
            $_.Group | Move-Item -Destination $dir
        } -ThrottleLimit $threads
}

Write-Output 'REFOLDER FINISHED: Ready for Next Step'

# Remove lines below if you want Powershell to close automatically after running.
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
exit
```

Comment: `ForEach-Object -Parallel` is [not really an improvement](https://github.com/santysq/Multithreading-Perfomance-on-PowerShell#results) over a normal `foreach` loop specially with disk I/O. If you really want speed use `ThreadJob` or `Runspace`.